# Avoid using functions for same result in mySql

Tags: mysql

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT e.evt_end, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(e.evt_end) AS unixTimeEND FROM events AS e   
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(e.evt_end) > '.time().' ORDER BY unixtimeEND;
```

I use two times the function UNIX_TIMESTAMP() to have the same result, and maybe it's a waste.
Is there a better way? I thought something like:

```
SELECT e.evt_end, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(e.evt_end) AS unixTimeEND FROM events AS e   
WHERE unixTimeEND > '.time().' ORDER BY unixtimeEND;
```

but didn't work

Comment: The columns that you select, you format them as you wish, so if you want a unix_timestmp then that is what you do. In the 'where' (selection criteria) then you have to get them in a format to do the required checks. It may be coincidence that you use the same function on the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously your second query wont work. **It will give collumn 'unixTimeEND' not found in WHERE clause**

> You can only use column aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING
>   clauses.
>
> Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a WHERE
>   clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE code is
>   executed, the column value may not yet be determined.

Answer (score 0):

you can use date() instead of time(). It lets you format any timestamp, current timestamp the default. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php For example

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // 2001-03-10 17:16:18 (the MySQL DATETIME format)
```